# GameCenter high scores doesn't include recently set score

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

After the game is over, scores (`reportables` is an array of `GKScore` objects) are reported:

```
GKScore.reportScores(reportables, withCompletionHandler: {(error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    Log.INFO("reportScores callback: \(error)")
  } else {
    Log.INFO("reported score")
    self.populate_high_scores(leaderboard)
  }
})
```

`populate_high_scores` sets up request to `GKLeaderboard`, then issues a call to retrieve the high scores:

```
request.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler({(scores, error) -> Void in
  self.populate_high_scores_handler(scores, error: error)
})
```

So to refresh:

1. User plays game.
2. High score reported to GameCenter.
3. <wait>
4. Callback received indicating success.
5. Request high scores from GameCenter.
6. <wait>
7. Receive high scores from GameCenter.

The scores that come back from the GameCenter do not include the score that was just saved. Note that on the *next* run through, the score will be returned. i.e. Current high score is 50. User plays game, scores 100. GameCenter returns the 50 score. User plays game again, scores 150. GameCenter returns the 100 score.

I'm not sure if this is a "feature" of the Sandbox mode of GameCenter, or if it's something I should work around.

I am, in fact, retrieving the correct subset of scores from the GameCenter (minus the most recently set score). Also, the request for high scores is definitely issued *after* GameCenter returns successfully from `reportScores`.

Comment: I just replaced my custom Game Over view/code with just popping up a Game Center leaderboard and noticed that the same problem occurs with Apple's code. So it's either sandbox only or a known bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game center is known to have issues with updating data while in the sandbox, developers get the lowest priority on the server.

Try testing your code in an off-peak time (mornings and the middle of the night worked best for me)

The other thing you can do is submit your scores and keep checking the leaderboards until it updates, then submit again to make sure everything is working.

I recently had this problem when submitting to 3 leaderboards at the same time, only some of them would update while i was testing, however the same code is live in the real world now and works without issue.